# Direct printing in class - python

Tags: python

I am new in 'class' methods, so sorry if somebody feel resentful. Every many people know this example:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, breadth, unit_cost=0):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth
        self.unit_cost = unit_cost

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.length + self.breadth)

    def get_area(self):
        return self.length * self.breadth

    def calculate_cost(self):
        area = self.get_area()
        return area * self.unit_cost
```

Now to get information we need to do such operation:

```
r = Rectangle(160, 120, 2000)
print("Area of Rectangle: %s cm^2" % (r.get_area()))
print("Cost of rectangular field: Rs. %s " %(r.calculate_cost()))
```

Result:

- Area of Rectangle: 19200 cm^2
- Cost of rectangular field: Rs. 38400000

But I dont do it this I need write this:

```
Rectangle(160, 120, 2000)
```

and get answer right now:

- Area of Rectangle: 19200 cm^2
- Cost of rectangular field: Rs. 38400000

I can use ordinary def myfunction: but I would like to do it by class.
Thanks for every help!

Comment: You may try to call the functions involved within `__init__()` method then print the result there. It should give you the results as soon as you create a new instance of `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__repr__` to make a printable representation of your class, then add a print statement from within `__init__` if you want to avoid using print outside of the class (you can make this optional).

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, breadth, unit_cost=0):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth
        self.unit_cost = unit_cost
        print(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        area_str = "Area of Rectangle: %s cm^2" % (self.get_area())
        cost_str = "Cost of rectangular field: Rs. %s " %(self.calculate_cost())
        return area_str + "\n" + cost_str

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.length + self.breadth)

    def get_area(self):
        return self.length * self.breadth

    def calculate_cost(self):
        area = self.get_area()
        return area * self.unit_cost
```

Output:

r = Rectangle(160, 120, 2000)

```
Area of Rectangle: 19200 cm^2
Cost of rectangular field: Rs. 38400000
```

Answer (score 4):

If you implement the code you wrote in the `print` statements as the class `__str__` method, you'll get that result by printing the class itself:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, breadth, unit_cost=0):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth
        self.unit_cost = unit_cost

    def __str__(self):
        return "Area of Rectangle: %s cm^2\nCost of rectangular field: Rs. %s " % (self.get_area(), self.calculate_cost())

    def get_perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.length + self.breadth)

    def get_area(self):
        return self.length * self.breadth

    def calculate_cost(self):
        area = self.get_area()
        return area * self.unit_cost
```

And the output:

```
>>> print(Rectangle(160, 120, 2000))                                                                                                                        
Area of Rectangle: 19200 cm^2
Cost of rectangular field: Rs. 38400000
```

This is a better design decision than adding a `print` statement to `__init__`, since it's relatively painless to add a `print` statement around the `Rectangle()` call, and it's more flexbile because you can still choose whether you want to display the output or not.

Comment: Works great, but I would like this result only without print

Comment: In that case simply add the line `print("Area of Rectangle: %s cm^2\nCost of rectangular field: Rs. %s " % (self.get_area(), self.calculate_cost()))` to the `__init__` method. But keep my last paragraph in mind.

Comment: Keep in mind that the behavior will be different depending on if you assign the object to a variable: r = Rectangle(160, 120, 2000), or just directly create the object: Rectangle(160, 120, 2000)